# How to increase the font in `paper` document class

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am using `paper` document class however the font defaults to a smaller size even if I mention explicitly any other sizes. How do I change it to a larger font size or override it ?

Edit: I couldn't find any other standard valid font sizes for the class .

Answer (score 1):

You gave no indication of what you did, or what error you got, but all the standard font size commands work in this class, the same as `article` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{paper}

\begin{document}

abc \Huge abc

\end{document}
```

As in `article` there are also `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` options to set the default font sizes and spacings, so you can use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{paper}
```